# Swift how to output int value in a textfield?

Tags: ios, swift

Alright, so I'm building an app that takes in a sequence of int values using a text field and encrypts it depending upon the initialized cipher. Originally I use the .toInt() function to covert my numerical string values into an array of integer. Then I add the cipher to each value in the array of integers however I'm having difficulty outputting the int array back to the text-field with the encrypted sequence. I have already thoroughly researched this and I can't seem to find an adequate function to convert my int array (named: code) back into a string which I can initialize as message1.text = the string numerical sequence.

Here is my code so far:

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var text: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Lable: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Button: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var message1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var Button2: UIButton!

var name = 0

@IBAction func Button(sender: UIButton) {
    name = text.text.toInt()!
}


@IBAction func Button2(sender: UIButton) {

    var code = Array (message1.text).map{String($0).toInt()! }



    for var n = 0 ; n < code.count; n++
    {
        code[n] = code[n] + name
    }

    var StringArray = (code : String()) // This is the mistake, I want to convert the code array into a joint string,

    message1.text = StringArray




}
```

I already know that what I attempted to do doesn't work cause when I run the app and press Button2 I'am left with no text at all in the text-field thus it is a legitimate statement that String array is not being initialized as expected.
Any help is much appreciated, Thank you for your time I'm starting off in app programming and I'm still struggling at relatively simple stuff so I understand if the answer might seem overly palpable.

Comment: Since you're starting out in programming, you should conform to the coding style that's standard for Swift (and objective-c too) before you develop bad habits -- property and function names should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: You are lying the word `cipher` improperly, it generally refers to encryption/decryption. It is best to explain exactly what you are doing. Converting between representations, string to int, etc is not using a `cipher`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is remap the values back to strings and join them:

```
var stringOfCodes = "".join( code.map { "\($0)" } )
```

This gives you a single string from the code values. I feel like there is a more elegant way to accomplish this, but this is what immediately came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a string out of an array:

```
 var spaceSeparatedString = " ".join(StringArray)
```

This will create a string out of the array using a space as the separator. Eg: "string1 string2 string3".